# Laravel: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

after installing a new laravel app 5.7 and trying to migrate I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = xxx_db and table_name = migrations)
>
> at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
>   660| // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll
>   format the error 661| // message to include the bindings with SQL,
>   which will make this exception a 662| // lot more helpful to the
>   developer instead of just the database's errors. 663| catch (Exception
>   $e) {
>
> 664| throw new QueryException( 665| $query,
>   $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e 666| ); 667| } 668|
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1 PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): The server requested
>   authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]")
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
>
> 2 PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=xxx_db ",
>   "root", "**********", [])
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Comment: already tried that solution but didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 43):

This query solved my problem.

```
 ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root@123';
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.4 :)

Comment: better solution than reinstall mysql. **pay attention to the command. The last "root" (... by 'root';) is the password, not the username

Comment: Worked for me on macOS!

Comment: worked for me on macOS for Server version: 8.0.21 - Homebrew. just want to mention 'some_password' can be your current working password as well, no need to set new password.

Comment: worked for me on Windows Server with laravel 8

Comment: Worked for Laravel 5.8 + MySQL 8. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

1. Enter to your mysql as root and run this query

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '1234';
```

You can change 1234 to be your password

2. Run these commands

> php artisan config:clear
>
> php artisan migrate

**Note:** this worked for me.

Comment: That worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Answer (score 5):

1. Re installed MySQL choosing Legacy Authentication Method as shown in iamge attached [SQL Authentication method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhpoI.png)
2. Database parameters in .env as follows

   ```
   DB_CONNECTION=mysql  
   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1  
   DB_PORT=3306  
   DB_DATABASE=database_name  
   DB_USERNAME=database_username  
   DB_PASSWORD=database_password(if any)
   ```
3. Database parameters in config/database.php

   ```
   'mysql' => [  
       'driver' => 'mysql',  
       'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),  
       'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),  
       'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),  
       'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name'),  
       'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'database_username'),  
       'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'database_password'),  
       'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),  
       'charset' => 'utf8mb4',  
       'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',  
       'prefix' => '',  
       'prefix_indexes' => true,  
       'strict' => true,  
       'engine' => null,  
       'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([  
           PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),  
       ]) : [],  
   ],
   ```
4. Run `php artisan migrate` from the projects terminal

Answer (score 5):

Solution is here with 2 step:

Step 1. You have to edit **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** file and append this setting in mysqld section:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
```

Step 2. Then run following mysql command:

```
CREATE USER 'new_root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'new_root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It is better if you restart your mysql service.

```
   sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

This problem happens when you have install mysql8 and your code compatible with mysql5

Answer (score 1):

By Providing DB_SOCKET in .env file this issue can be resolved like this :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=my_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Not related to my case but good to know that socket configuration is that easy in Laravel! :O

Answer (score 1):

Please Check Server localhost Port on phpmyadmin and .env file like (3306,3307,8889)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=masterpass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `Mysql installer - Community` (if you are in windows) and then reconfigure `mysql server` to use legacy authentication method. it should be solve your problem without pain.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly you changes your mysql user or password. If you user/password changed then go to .env file and change your phpmyadmin user and password. Give your database name

```
DB_DATABASE=hrms
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are getting through this kind of issue like me, avoid losing your time**

My scenario: I had to start an existing `Laravel5.1` application on `PHP5.6`. Docker didn't helped me, so I had to create a virtual machine for that.

This issue happens because of the authentication driver for MySQL. On version 8, it will use `caching_sha2_password` (and Laravel 5 doesn't know what to do with this.

One way to correct this is to downgrade your MySQL version back to `5.7`. I've tried a lot, but my apt crashed after "forcing" it to downloading 5.7. If you want to try, [heres a discussion](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-properly-downgrade-from-mysql-8-to-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04) for it.

95% of other discussions on StackOverflow and other forums will say to you just ALTER your MySQL user for the `mysql_native_password`. For some reason, it **DOES NOT** work. Even after restarting mysql services and flushing it's privileges, doesn't work. I've tried this kind of solutions for hours.

Luckily we have a hero in THIS discussion and is **@Amir Hosseinzadeh**. You have to create a new user AFTER changing the MySQL driver configuration. Just follow his/her solution on top and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your .env file and make sure `DB_CONNECTION=mysql`and DB connections are correct.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I have follow below steps, which is the combination of above multiple answers :

**NOTICE : For this laravel 5.1 version, php version should be <= 7.2**

Step 1 :  You have to edit **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** file and append this setting in mysqld section:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
```

Step 2 :

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '1234';
```

Step 3 :

```
   sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Step 4 :

```
php artisan config:clear && php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers - this is a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71618362/1116230