# How to resolve: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-valet

I get the error whenever I try to access the route created with valet `home.test`. I have tried all the solutions listed in similar issues like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607322/laravel-sqlstatehy000-2054-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unkno) but nothing seems to work

The error is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method 
unknown to the client (SQL: select * from `user_meta` where `user_id` is null limit 1)
```

```
MySQL version - 8.0.19
PHP version - 7.4.7
```

My migrations work fine as I can see the tables created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update`.env` config

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=home
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=abcd

TENANCY_HOST=localhost
TENANCY_PORT=3306
TENANCY_DATABASE=home
TENANCY_USERNAME=root
TENANCY_PASSWORD=abcd
```

Comment: Post your Database configurations from env

Comment: This may help you [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53881212/6189461)

Comment: This was happening to me when using laravel but running commands such as `migrate` from the wrong shell. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910286/241138

Answer (score 5):

I guess this query solved your problem.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to change MySQL settings. Edit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file and put this setting in mysqld section:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
```

Then run following command:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then you may need to restart the mysql services for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: I tried every solution possible, but this was the only one that worked.